# jquery datatable and mouse position

Tags: jquery, datatables, mouse-position

I'm using datatable plugin and when the mousemove happen in some element, the coordination of the mouse are relatives to before the datatable was rendered. How can I get the current position considering the rendered table?

Comment: I just want the real x/y coordination

Comment: absolutely no way of knowing what issue is without seeing how you are binding to the event..post your code

Comment: The real x y coordinates relative to the document? The screen? The element?